# How to Execute Android Asyntask several times

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an android speech recognition system that uses Asyntask for background recognition purpose. My code is as following. I wanted to call the Asyntask's execute everytime I pushed the start button to recognize my speech, but it seemed the Asyntask can only be exectued once. There's a crash if I call it another time. Please don't suggest create a new Asyntask each time because instantiating it causes the UI thread to skip hundreds of frames, and it made the user experience awkwardly slow.

What can I do to fix this problem?

```
public class PocketSphinxAndroidDemo extends Activity {

    private class RecognitionTask
            extends AsyncTask<AudioRecord, Void, Hypothesis> {

        Decoder decoder;
        Config config;


        public RecognitionTask() {


            Config config = Decoder.defaultConfig();

            decoder = new Decoder(config);
        }

        protected void doInBackground(AudioRecord... recorder) {
            int nread;
            short[] buf = new short[1024];

            decoder.startUtt(null);
            while ((nread = recorder[0].read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0)
                decoder.processRaw(buf, nread, false, false);
            decoder.endUtt();
            return decoder.hyp();               
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
            if (null != hypothesis)
                speechResult.append("\n" + hypothesis.getHypstr());
            else
                speechResult.append("\n<no speech>");
        }
    }

    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
    }

    private TextView speechResult;
    private AudioRecord recorder;
    private RecognitionTask recTask;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        speechResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SpeechResult);

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                                   SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                   AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 8192);
        recTask = new RecognitionTask();
    }

    public void onToggleRecognition(View view) {
        if (!(view instanceof ToggleButton))
            return;

        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
            recorder.startRecording();
            recTask.execute(recorder);
        } else {
            recorder.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a thread and looper http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: You cant try threads for you purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Looper and Thread as recommended by Raghunandan, Moreover the crash you were getting is may be you are using the same object to execute your AsyncTask. If you want to call your async task again you must create a new object and then execute your AsyncTask.

Like this

```
 new MyAsyncTask().execute("");
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but as I said, instantiating a new one each time makes the UI painful to respond. you can experience a very significant delay in the user interface, because I have a lot other objects to be instantiated inside new AsyncTask(), which would be needed later in doInBackground()

Comment: You don't need to call it in the main thread, Thats why i have mentioned create a seprate thread and then call async task from there.

Comment: then I Will refer you to this.............

"There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)"

Answer (score 0):

yes..as per android doc it can be executed only once..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . From                 my exp,after `postexecute` method it will be cancelled.so use like

```
new RecognitionTask().execute(recorder)
```

and create those Decoder,Config variables inside activity..and pass it explicitly to task..